# @memberof for shared class methods?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

In my library I am extending types `Database` and `Transaction` with the same method `query` defined in just one place.

If I try to use `@memberof Database` and `@memberof Transaction`, the latter overrides the former.

What is the correct way in `jsdoc` to indicate for a function that it represents a method in two different classes?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
/**
 * @interface Interface
 * ...
 */

 /**
  * @function query
  * @memberof Interface
  * ...
  */

/**
 * @class Database
 * @implements Interface
 * ...
 */

/**
 * @class Transaction
 * @implements Interface
 * ...
 */
```

It doesn't necessary matter that `Interface` isn't defined anywhere in the code as long as no one else wants to implement `Interface`. If you think they might, then make and extend a base class instead (using prototype inheritance or ES6 classes), and document accordingly.

Comment: Will `Interface` not pop-up in the help system as a result? I wouldn't want an unexisting item there.

Comment: @vitaly-t I'm not sure. It might depend on your IDE. Could you try it?

Comment: Why would it depend on my IDE? I'm just using this library: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc

Comment: @vitaly-t You referred to a pop-up in the help system. I thought you meant your IDE.

Comment: @vitaly-t If you don't want `Interface` to show in your generated documentation, you can hide it with `@private`. `query` should still show up in `Database` and `Transaction`.

Comment: @vitaly-t Alternatively, you can go the base-class route so that "`Interface`" actually has corresponding code.

Comment: I wouldn't write additional code just the documentation works, that's the wrong intensive. And by `pop-up` I meant simply to `show`, not that it would literally pop up :)

Comment: @vitaly-t If I were in your shoes, I would decide if it's more semantic for "`Interface`" to be an interface or a class, and act accordingly. If it makes sense as a base class, then moving `query` to that class doesn't count as *additional* code; it would just be the code you already have, but on the prototype of a `function`.

Comment: I just tried the suggested solution, it didn't work at all. The method isn't added anywhere.

Comment: @vitaly-t Make sure you remove the ellipses. It should work fine; I just tried it